# Where does Curve25519's limit occur?

Tags: privatekey, algorithm, curve25519, key-collision

While informing myself on the inner-working of Monero, I stumbled on Curve25519.

The [CryptoNote White Paper](https://cryptonote.org/whitepaper.pdf) states:

> l: a prime order of the base point; l = 2^252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493;
>   [...]
>   private ec-key is a standard elliptic curve private key: a number a ∈ [1, l − 1];

Another [Stack Exchange answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/4114/4798) states the following:

> All you need protocol-wise is a private spend key and a private view key, where a private key is just some number smaller than `l` where `l` is a prime order of the EC curve basepoint `l=2^252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493`. Anything bigger than that will get wrapped around ie `a` and `a+l` are equivalent.

From my understanding this means that a private key `a` has the same derived public key as private key `a+l`.

I've however been unable to reproduce the said "*wrapping*".

Using a *very* random `a=0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111` I [calculated](https://defuse.ca/big-number-calculator.htm) `a+l=0x2111111111111111111111111111111125f00aefb408ade76923742b6e06e4fe`.

I then tried to use `a` and `a+l` on [llcoins](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html) as Hexadecimal Seed, as Private Spend Key or as Private View Key. They never generated the same results.

Does the wrapping occurring on `a` ,when greater or equal to `l`, occur at another step? Does it only occur sometimes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It will get wrapped around because it's later passed through sc_reduce32 function which performs `mod l` operation on the input.

See below example using [silent Matt's big int library](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jtobey/javascript-bignum/master/biginteger.js) which is loaded with [llcoins](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html). Easiest to just open the developer tab and type stuff into JS console.

To calculate 2^252 + 27742317777372353535851937790883648493:

```
l = JSBigInt(2).pow(252).add(JSBigInt.parse("27742317777372353535851937790883648493",10));
```

To print out the number in base16:

```
l.toString(16);
"1000000000000000000000000000000014DEF9DEA2F79CD65812631A5CF5D3ED"
```

That's the `l`. If you swap byes and feed it as seed to [llcoins](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html), you should get `0x0` as seed. Try inputting `EDD3F55C1A631258D69CF7A2DEF9DE1400000000000000000000000000000010` (little endian) as seed and you'll get `0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` as private key.

Now, we can also do the addition from your example:

```
a = JSBigInt.parse("0x1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111");
BigInteger {_d: Array(11), _s: 1}
c = l.add(a);
BigInteger {_d: Array(11), _s: 1}
c.toString(16);
"2111111111111111111111111111111125F00AEFB408ADE76923742B6E06E4FE"
```

Performing `mod l` will give you:

```
c.remainder(l).toString(16);
"1111111111111111111111111111110FC3217326E19743AB8FEADF6B41B3D24"
```

observe how you don't get the value of `a` because `a` itself is bigger than `l`:

```
a.remainder(l).toString(16);
"1111111111111111111111111111110FC3217326E19743AB8FEADF6B41B3D24"
```

so adding `l` to this will give you the original number:

```
a.remainder(l).add(l).toString(16);
"1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"
```

If you swap endian of `c` and feed it as seed to [llcoins](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html), you'll get the same remainder but with little endian byte order:

`seed=FEE4066E2B742369E7AD08B4EF0AF02511111111111111111111111111111121`

`privSpend=243d1bb4f6adfeb83a74196e321732fc10111111111111111111111111111101`

Comment: Add which step? I discovered that using the `a+l` as seed is the same as using the private key generated by `a+l` as seed. However this private key is not the `mod l` of `a+l`.

Comment: It should be. If you're doing it by other means, pay attention to byte endianness, though. Using your calc, `l=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0BCA1161B7C687A4B21172333C8170C38FC05F0D`, `l+a=11111111111111111111111101cdb2272c8d798b5c32283444d9281d4a0d1701e` and `mod l = 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111`.

Comment: How did you find `l=FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0BCA1161B7C687A4B21172333C8170C38F‌​C05F0D`? When does the switch of endianness occur?

Comment: I used JS BigInt lib to play with this a while ago and computed hex value of l from whitepaper definition. See my code here: https://github.com/JollyMort/monero-wallet-generator/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I know it's a lot to ask but do you by any chance still have the code used to compute it or the motivation to make a quick [runkit](https://npm.runkit.com/big-integer)? I've been trying for 2 days to understand and achieve the conversion but I keep running into another hex representation of `l`. I've been searching without success another post explaining this through the [crypto.se] portal. I've tried to check [llcoin](https://xmr.llcoins.net/addresstests.html)'s source but they link it to the `C++` Monero library.

Comment: Check my updated answer with some examples, I have no idea how I got the `FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF0BCA1161B7C687A4B21172333C8170C38F‌​C05F0D`, must have messed up somewhere. The updated answer has correct values :)